# Meaning of irreducible polynomial that is factor of $P$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, irreducible-polynomials

I am reading the following lemma about polynomials:

> Suppose that $x$ is a root of a polynomial $P$, $\pmod p$. Then the
> irreducible polynomial $(T - x)$ is a factor of $P$

I am not sure I understand this. Let's say we have the polynomial $P = 3T - 5, \pmod 7$.
The root of this polynomial is $x \equiv 4 \pmod 7$.
But now how can I combine this with the lemma above to figure out the irreducible polynomial that is a factor of $P$? I guess it means $(T - 4)$ is a factor of $P$ does that just mean that $P = 3(T - 4)$? If yes, how is this representation useful?

Comment: Obviously $P = 3(T-4)$. Just do the math - we have $3(T - 4) = 3T - 12 = 3T - 5$ since we;re working in $\mathbb{Z}/(7)$. It's useful because it helps us to factor polynomials.

Comment: Well, factoring linear polynomials isn't very interesting.  Try factoring $x^3-1\pmod 7$ noting that $x=2$ is a root.

Comment: @MarkSaving: I can understand that factoring a polynomial is useful in general, I am just not clear specifically in the context of modulo. Is there some example that it helps?

Comment: @lulu:$(x-1)(x-2)(x-4)$ I see, thanks!